Almost surely convergence of $X_i$ where $P(X_i = 1) = \frac{1}{i^2}$
I am told that the sequence of independent random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ where $$P(X_i = 1) = \frac{1}{i^2}$$ $$P(X_i = 0) = 1 - \frac{1}{i^2}$$
converge almost surely to the constant variable $X = 0$. Indeed, for all $\epsilon > 0$, $$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}P(X_n > \epsilon) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}P(X_n = 1) < \infty$$
So, $$X_n \xrightarrow{\text{a.s}} X$$
But, when I tried this myself, I noticed that for the $X_i$ to converge to $0$, since $X_i$ only take values of $0$ and $1$, it must be true that for some $n \geq 1$, $X_i = 0 
\text{ } \forall i \geq n$
I let $$A_n = \{X_i = 0 \text{ for all } i \geq n\}$$
Then, $$P(X_n \rightarrow 0)$$
$$= P\bigg(\bigcup_{i \geq 1}A_i\bigg)$$
$$= P\bigg(A_1 \cup \bigcup_{i \geq 2} (A_i \backslash A_{i - 1}) \bigg)$$
$$= P(A_1) + \sum_{i \geq 2} P(A_i \backslash A_{i - 1})$$
$$=\sum_{i \geq 2} P(A_i \backslash A_{i - 1})$$
$$=\sum_{i \geq 2} \frac{1}{(i-1)^2} \cdot \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{i^2}\bigg)\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{(i+1)^2}\bigg) \ldots$$
I would want to show that this sum $= 1$, but don't know how to proceed further. In particular, I would be happy if there is a general way which I could extend to any $p > 1$. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.
Thanks

You have made mistakes in computation. For example, $P(X_{n+1}=0)=1-\frac 1 {(n+1)^{2}} \neq \frac {n^{2}}{n^{2}+1}$

@geetha290krm Thank you very much! I have fixed the mistake now.

It's easier to show that not converging has probability 0. When you want the answer somewhat spoiled, look up the Borel-Cantelli lemma.
